# Zookeeper in cloud implementation

Tags: solr

I want to implement Zookeeper architecture in my environment with the help of cloud architecture ,provide a steps by step  to implement.

Thanks,
A.Uma maheswar

Comment: Did you tried anything at your end?

Comment: i wan to implement now,i did not tried previously.

Comment: So what do you actually want to do? Sorry, but this question does not make sense by itself.